# node.js static assets proxy

Tags: node.js, express

In my Express app I have a route defined like this:

```
// catch-all for static assets used by the UI
app.get('*', require('./lib/routes/static'));
```

I want to proxy the requests for static files to a webserver running elsewhere. For this I have written this piece of middleware:

```
// static.js
var request = require('request');

// static assets are served through another webserver to which we proxy
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  var host = process.env.UI_URL;
  var url = req.url;

  request(host + url, function(err, proxyRes) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    }
    // if the resource is a 404, serve `index.html` served by the `host` to enable using the `pushState` API in the browser
    if (proxyRes.statusCode === 404) {
      request(host).pipe(res);
    }
    // if the resource is not a 404, pipe the proxy response into the response to the original request
    else {
      proxyRes.pipe(res);
    }
  });
};
```

When I hit a bogus url like `/asd/asd`, the app gets the `index.html` file no problem. So the logic branch for a `404` works as expected. But when the browser is trying to get static resources referenced in `index.html`, the request just hangs eventually timing out and yielding a „no data received”. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use express? http is enough, isn't it?

Comment: It is not, what I provided is just part of a bigger app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the problem with line:

```
proxyRes.pipe(res);
```

By the time node will reach that line whole response stream will be already finished. Apparently 'request' module waits for whole stream before calling handler function. Otherwise they would not be able to pass 3rd argument with body.

The easiest solution would be to send back body already saved by 'request':

```
 request(host + url, function(err, proxyRes, body) {
   ...
   else {
     res.send(body);
   }
 }
```

, but this will not work with images and other binary content, because body is already decoded string.

To make it work with binary resources, you need to buffer response from proxy, starting on proxy making request. Then eventually later, depending on response you may decide to stream it back to browser. You also need to pass through headers, so browser get information how to properly decode binary body content.

```
// static.js
var request = require('request'),
    stream = require('stream'),
    util = require('util');

function Buffer() {
  var pumping = true,
      queue = [],
      push = this.push.bind(this);

  function flush() {
    if (!pumping) return;
    while (queue.length && (pumping = push.apply({}, queue.shift())));
  }
  this._read = function () {
    pumping = true;
    flush();
  };
  this._write = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {
    queue.push([chunk, encoding]);
    callback();
  };
  stream.Duplex.call(this);
}
util.inherits(Buffer, stream.Duplex);

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    var host = process.env.UI_URL,
        url = req.url,
        buffer = new Buffer();

  request(host + url, function(err, proxyRes, body) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    }
    if (proxyRes.statusCode === 404) {
      request(host).pipe(res);
    }
    else {
      res.set(proxyRes.headers);
      buffer.pipe(res);
    }
  }).pipe(buffer);
});
```

I hope you find the example useful.

Comment: Following example has significant memory footprint for requests with large files. The 'request' module will wait for whole response before calling your handler. It will have huge memory footprint on server, because it will need to store whole body content before even starting sending data back to browser.

If you need to have it working with large files you should consider using some alternate solution, which will do stream processing on the fly. I have used 'http-proxy' with great success for that. You can see an example at: https://gist.github.com/szarsti/7266806

Comment: thanks, that seems to be the problem; the request lib works differently than built-in node http streams, so that's slightly confusing and surprising; using node-http-proxy seems to do the trick, although nice tackling the problem with a custom stream :)